# How do I assign my .reduce function output to a variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

Given an object and a key, `getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty` returns an array containing all the elements of the array located at the given key that are equal to ten.

I want to assign what my `.reduce` method outputs to a variable then use that variable inside my `if` statement. My code evaluates to `NaN`.

```
function getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, key) {
  var arrayTotal = 0;
  obj[key].reduce(function(a,b){
    arrayTotal = a + b;
   });
  if(arrayTotal === 10) {
    return obj[key];
  }
};
```

Comment: The `reduce` function callback should return a value, see the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a

Comment: First of all, thank you for helping me out with this. Its month 5 of learning JS and while I've learned a ton, there are still many things I am still trying to process and learn so please bear with me if I come across as a complete novice haha.

As for the code, I know it returns the value, but my question is how to I get that value, then use a comparison operator such as (===)  to compare the sum of the array and make sure its equal to 10?

In short, what I am trying to do is to get what returns to me from .reduce, assign it to a variable.

Thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're approaching `reduce` incorrectly. You're almost using it like `Array#forEach`. Remember that callbacks are functions. They expect to `return` an actual value.

When you read the docs, you'll see that reduce also needs an `accumulator`, that is an argument after the callback.

```
const sum = obj[key].reduce(function(a,b){
  return a + b
}, 0)
```

Or if you want the newer and prettier version:

```
const sum = obj[key].reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)
```

When you have a one liner, `return` is implicit, which means it's implied, as opposed to explicit.

The accumulator is what your value starts at while it totals up the values.

```
Array.reduce(callback, accumulator)
```